# Can't find option to activate legacy boot mode on Asus EFI BIOS

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, uefi

I installed Windows 10 on a PC but it has some incompatibilities with the graphic card. Now I want to install Windows 7, so I burned the ISO on an USB stick, and then I tried to boot the system with it. Instead of launching Windows 7 installer, the computer is booting directly to Windows 10.

I read some stuff over the internet that for Windows 7 installer to be bootable, I need to set the BIOS to legacy mode. However, on ASUS EFI BIOS version 2.00.1201, I can't find this option anywhere. I selected the **Boot** tab and all I have is this:

> **Bootup NumLock State**
>
> **Full Screen Logo**
>
> **Wait For 'F1' If Error**
>
> **Option ROM Messages**
>
> **Setup Mode**
>
> *Boot Option Priorities*
>
> **Boot Option #1**
>
> **Boot Option #2**
>
> **> Hard Drive BBS Priorities**
>
> *Boot Override*
>
> **> SAMSUMG HD**
>
> **> Windows Boot Manager**

Now, where is the option of setting boot mode to legacy?

Comment: Can you re-check the same while having the USB stick connected?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. When I connect the USB stick, the only diference is that I have another Boot Option (#3) that says: UEFI: General USB Flash Disk. Also on Boot Override category I have options General USB Flash Disk and UEFI: General USB Flash Disk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some ASUS firmwares (e.g. "Aptio"), there is no such global choice – *all* available boot options are merged into a single menu (press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to open the boot menu one-time).

BIOS-mode boot entries always describe a specific *disk* rather than a specific OS (since they only boot the MBR 'bootcode' and don't know the OS name, unlike UEFI-mode boot entries which do). Of course, it's *not impossible* that an UEFI boot entry would be named after a disk, but that's rather unlikely...

For removable media, UEFI-mode entries also have an `UEFI:` prefix, while BIOS-mode entries either don't (as in your case) or are prefixed with `BIOS:` (on some other computers).

Therefore your options are:

- `SAMSUMG HD` – BIOS
- `Windows Boot Manager` – UEFI (stored in NVRAM)
- `General USB Flash Disk` – BIOS
- `UEFI: General USB Flash Disk` – UEFI (autodetected from removable drive)

Comment: When I select the BIOS options (SAMSUMG HD or General USB Flash Disk) I get a black scree, with a underscore on top left, as if nothing gets booted (not even the OS). What does that mean?

Comment: Maybe it means you should try another tool for making the Win7 USB? (I've had good luck with Rufus.) Test with a random Linux ISO, too.

Answer (score 0):

If the Bios is ONLY UEFI (no legacy option), you can boot from USB if is formatted FAT32 and not NTFS. Many of new PC's/laptop's have only the newer UEFI BIOS (the Legacy Bios is an older option).

1. Download Rufus (freeware, please use the at least the current latest version 3.8)
2. Make a bootable USB flash drive, formatted in FAT32 (!)
3. Put in the PC's, Laptop's USB port.
4. Power on the PC/Laptop and push the <kbd>ESC</kbd> (can be <kbd>F8</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, etc.. depending on the PC) until you get into the boot selection section.
5. Boot from the USB.
6. Enjoy installing Windows!

Answer (score 0):

There's another incompatibility:
IF your System calls for bootx64.efi you will only be capable of install Windows 10 and above.
Older OSs use bootia32.efi instead.
Newer Systems don't call for bootia32.efi anymore.
.efi files are located in your install media, in the \efi\boot folder.